# C++ Quantlib EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, quantlib

I've been trying to run some of the example code (BermudanSwaption) in Xcode but keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2.

But compiling and running the BermudanSwaption code in the terminal works correctly.

The following code throws the same error in Xcode.

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace QuantLib;

int main (){
    Date date(18, March, 2014);
    std::cout << date << std::endl;
}
```

And this runs correctly.

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/boost main.cpp  -o main -L/opt/local/lib/ -lQuantLib
```

Are there some specific settings I need to tweak in Xcode in order for this to run?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it

Comment: I found that #including the individual libraries separately rather then including ql/quanlib to work. So in my example sub ql/quantlib.hpp with ql/time/date.hpp and everything runs fine.

Comment: Nice, it works for me too! Please add that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found that #including the individual libraries separately rather then including ql/quanlib to work. So in my example sub ql/quantlib.hpp with ql/time/date.hpp and everything runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of Kaush, and a bit of trial and error, the following works for me in QuantLib 1.4, and means you don't have to add in every single individual library:

In `<ql/experimental/models/all.hpp>`, comment out these lines:

```
#include <ql/experimental/models/kahalesmilesection.hpp>
#include <ql/experimental/models/markovfunctional.hpp>
```